# Area Similarity Question

Tags: geometry

[image: Sorry about this huge image.]

Given this diagram, what is the ratio of the area of triangle ABC to triangle ABD?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Use similar triangles.

$[\triangle ABC]:[\triangle ABD]=BC:AD$ , as they have the same height $AB$.

Comment: When I do this, I get 16:9. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: No. Can you see a pair of similar triangles?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I believe I understand what you mean now. I used similar triangles BCE and DAE. Is the ratio of the areas of ABC and ABD 2 to 3?

Comment: Yes. I have the same answer.